# Styling Generic Component with Styled Components

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

I'm running into annoying typescript errors when trying to style my generic component like follows:

```js
const StyledParentComponent = styled(ParentComponent)`
  ${GenericComponent} {
    ...
  }
`;
```

It throws a bunch of errors about JSX not being assignable to some Interpolation type.

Here is a small example that produces the error:

```js
import styled from "styled-components";

const ParentComponent = () => {
  return (
    <ParentComponentContainer>
      <GenericComponent value={10} />
    </ParentComponentContainer>
  );
};

interface GenericComponentProps<T> {
  value: T;
  className?: string;
}

const GenericComponent = <T,>({
  value,
  className,
}: GenericComponentProps<T>) => {
  console.log(value);

  return (
    <GenericComponentContainer>
      Logging generic component value
    </GenericComponentContainer>
  );
};

const GenericComponentContainer = styled.div``;

const RegularComponent = () => {
  return <RegularContainer></RegularContainer>;
};

const RegularContainer = styled.div``;

const ParentComponentContainer = styled.div` 
  // this is where it will throw the error
  ${GenericComponent} {
    display: flex;
  }

  ${RegularContainer} {
    display: flex;
  }
`;
```

I was running what the standard pattern is for dealing with this issue. It's important that I'm able to style it this way so that I can have generic components as children and be able to style them with the above pattern.

Answer (score 0):

I think using React Component in `styled.div()` is very unusual.
I've never seen it done before. How about we try this approach instead?

First, forward the className props to `GenericComponentContainer`.

```
const GenericComponent = <T,>({
  value,
  className,
}: GenericComponentProps<T>) => {
  console.log(value);

  return (
    // Must forward the `className` prop!
    <GenericComponentContainer className={className}>
      Logging generic component value
    </GenericComponentContainer>
  );
};

const GenericComponentContainer = styled.div``;
```

And then, styling `GenericComponent` with styled.

```
const ParentComponentContainer = styled.div` 
  ${RegularContainer} {
    display: flex;
  }
`;

const StyledGenericComponent = styled(GenericComponent)`
   display: flex;
`;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your `GenericComponent` itself needs to be `styled(GenericComponent)` in order to be used within a style block.

We use something like this in our codebase.

```
const StyledGenericComponent = styled(GenericComponent)`
  color: green;
`;

const Container = styled.div`
  ${StyledGenericComponent} {
      color: red;
  }
`;
```

However to keep the generic types flowing through we have to use a `satisfies`.

```
const StyledGenericComponent = styled(GenericComponent)``
  satisfies typeof GenericComponent;
```